# how to use git from another directory?

Tags: git

Assume there is folder structure like:

```
repos
    /repo1  <-- here is git repository
```

I do:

```
cd repos
```

And how can I now use repository in `/repo1` still being in `repos` directory? I don't want to do

```
cd repo1
git status (...)
git commit (...)
...
```

but something like:

```
git --git-dir=repo1 (...)
```

or

```
git --work-tree=repo1 (...)
```

I want to do *ALL* git commands in that style, event `git init`. What's the correct approach?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why exactly would you like to do it this way?

Comment: because I want to micromanage many repositiores from one place in a script

Comment: Can't you just jump between the working directories back and forth in the script? You seem to have their paths. You also have `cd -` to "undo" last cd (i.e. go back to the previous working directory).

Comment: maybe that would work, I'm using python and subprocesses - why not make 'cd' there. Anyway, I found something that works - look below. Later if necessary I'll look for more optimal way.

Comment: Ok, I'm not much familiar with Python and especially subprocesses so I can't help much :) Anyway, try to add info *why* you want to do X the next time -- basically include as much info in the question as possible -- because as you see, possible answers may vary ;)

Comment: sure, thanks for feedback. Sometimes it's good to add big picture, even if I know that I want to ask only for one piece :)

Answer (score 10):

Git has the `-C <path>` option (like `tar -C <path>`) that changes the working directory for Git to `path` and then executes the command in that directory. Example run:

```
$ mkdir gitrepo
$ git -C gitrepo init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/foo/gitrepo/.git/
```

`man git`:

> `-C <path>`
>
> Run as if git was started in `<path>` instead of the current working directory. When multiple `-C` options are given, each subsequent non-absolute `-C <path>` is interpreted relative to the preceding `-C <path>`.
>
> This option affects options that expect path name like `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` in that their interpretations of the path names would be made relative to the working directory caused by the `-C` option. For example the following invocations are equivalent:
>
> ```
> git --git-dir=a.git --work-tree=b -C c status
> git --git-dir=c/a.git --work-tree=c/b status
> ```

My version of Git is 2.16.1.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the environment  variable `$GIT_DIR`. Look it up.

Comment: I didn't check your solution, but tried --git-dir and --work-tree and started to work. But another issue arises: when I use remote repository in `/repo1` using relative path, then operating on repository `/repo1` from another dir (`repos`) causes that this relative path isn't preserved; it's calculated from folder I'm operating from.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` to operate on a repo outside the current directory:

```
git --git-dir=/some/other/dir/.git --work-tree=/some/other/dir status
```

You can also set `GIT_DIR` as @opqdonut mentioned, but you'll also have to set `GIT_WORK_TREE`. Note that `GIT_DIR` is the path to the `.git` directory in the target repository, and `GIT_WORK_TREE` is the target repository itself.

This is all really convenient, but here's a shell function that will make your life easier:

```
function git-dir() {
    dir=$1
    shift
    git --git-dir="$dir/.git" --work-tree="$dir" $*
}
```

That will work in Bash or Zsh (and probably other Bourne-derived shells). Put it in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` or wherever is appropriate for your environment.

Then you can just do this:

```
git-dir /some/other/dir status
```

Where `status` is any Git command.  It works with other arguments as well, which are passed directly to the `git` command:

```
git-dir /some/other/dir remote -v
```