# Get commit list between two tags of another repo in git

Tags: git

So I have repo A which has tags for different releases. In repo B, how can I get the commit list between two tags of repo A?

I know that if I'm in repo A, I can do something like `git log --pretty=oneline tag1..tag2`. Is there a way I can get the same result but from within repo B?

I was hoping for something similar to a `--repo` parameter that would allow me to specify a repo to look for tags from. Only solution I've been able to find is completely cloning repo A into repo B to allow access to the tags, but that isn't ideal.

EDIT: For more clarity, repo B contains a shared Github Actions Workflow, within which I want to be able to run a command to access the commit history between two tags of given repo, in this example, repo A. It's structured this way as there are other repos using the same workflow (repo C, D, etc.)

Comment: You might be looking for the `-C` option. [how-to-use-git-from-another-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430613/how-to-use-git-from-another-directory)

Comment: hmm, this works locally when I'm going between two different directories/folders but I'm not sure if/how this would work on Github when I have two different repos?

Comment: how/why would you use that on Github?

Comment: good q, I updated the question description to hopefully provide some more clarity on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is 100% local, so you can't do anything without a local repo.

Unless the repository is extremely large, you can simply checkout the full history and run git commands against that.

> If you reuse a workflow from a different repository, any actions in the called workflow run as if they were part of the caller workflow. For example, ***if the called workflow uses actions/checkout, the action checks out the contents of the repository that hosts the caller workflow, not the called workflow.***

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```

You could save some disk space with `git clone -n --filter=blob:none` to only clone the commits, not the files. However, Github's checkout action should be very efficient; it doesn't actually have to download anything.

---

Otherwise, you can use the [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest?apiVersion=2022-11-28), but that's more complicated.